# Issue in Heap dump analysis - Java 8

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection

We observed 90% heap memory usage on our server (tomcat 8.0.33) and started its analysis (after taking heap dump using `jmap -dump:format=b` command).

**Details**-

- Server OS - Linux
- Application server - tomcat 8.0.33
- Total memory on server - 16 GB
- Xms and Xmx value - 8 GB
- Heap memory used - 7.8 GB

**Jstat -gc output -**

[image: Jstat -gc output]

**Top command output-**

[image: Top command output]

**Visual vm total memory -**

[image: Visual vm total memory]

**Visual vm details** -

[image: Visual vm details]

[image: Sar output]

GC logs for today:

```
2016-11-02T00:16:58.013-0400: 1791653.461: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1948352K->147200K(1949184K)] 7468597K->5677221K(8240640K), 0.0726273 secs] [Times: user=0.17 sys=0.00, real=0.08 secs] 
2016-11-02T01:08:58.585-0400: 1794774.033: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1948416K->147136K(1949184K)] 7478437K->5686965K(8240640K), 0.0704435 secs] [Times: user=0.17 sys=0.00, real=0.07 secs] 
2016-11-02T02:00:28.573-0400: 1797864.021: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1948352K->147104K(1949184K)] 7488181K->5696733K(8240640K), 0.0731509 secs] [Times: user=0.17 sys=0.00, real=0.08 secs] 
2016-11-02T03:15:56.104-0400: 1802391.552: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1948320K->143664K(1945088K)] 7497949K->5703005K(8236544K), 0.0677412 secs] [Times: user=0.16 sys=0.00, real=0.07 secs] 
2016-11-02T04:08:41.166-0400: 1805556.614: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1944880K->135696K(1945600K)] 7504221K->5704773K(8237056K), 0.0684821 secs] [Times: user=0.15 sys=0.00, real=0.07 secs] 
2016-11-02T05:00:58.618-0400: 1808694.066: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1932816K->127504K(1925120K)] 7501893K->5706357K(8216576K), 0.0649463 secs] [Times: user=0.15 sys=0.00, real=0.06 secs] 
2016-11-02T05:53:38.105-0400: 1811853.553: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1924624K->119504K(1937408K)] 7503477K->5707941K(8228864K), 0.0910155 secs] [Times: user=0.22 sys=0.00, real=0.09 secs] 
2016-11-02T06:46:23.946-0400: 1815019.394: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1904336K->111312K(1896448K)] 7492773K->5709485K(8187904K), 0.0652027 secs] [Times: user=0.15 sys=0.00, real=0.06 secs]
```

**Question**:

Why is Visual Vm showing total memory of around 1300 MB only, whereas top command shows total memory as 7.5 GB. I understand that there could be memory utilization of non-heap memory as well, but jstat command also confirms memory usage much higher than 1300 MB. Is it not shown correctly on visual vm?

What is the miss in analysis?

---

**Edit**:

On further investigation it seems that there might be issue heap dump itself. Found article which says how heap dump generated using java 8 might not work. Also while trying to analyze heap dump using jhat, following warning were generated

```
WARNING:  Failed to resolve object id 0x78281aec0 for field first (signature L)
WARNING:  Failed to resolve object id 0x78391e800 for field unfinalized (signatu
WARNING:  Failed to resolve object id 0x5c07e9958 for field clazz (signature L)
WARNING:  Failed to resolve object id 0x5c07e9700 for field clazz (signature L)
WARNING:  Failed to resolve object id 0x5c07e94f8 for field clazz (signature L)
WARNING:  Failed to resolve object id 0x5c07e9368 for field clazz (signature L)
WARNING:  Failed to resolve object id 0x5c07e90f0 for field clazz (signature L)
```

Is there a different way to generate heap dump which can be analyzed correctly?

Comment: Likely the total memory displayed by visual VM is the one allocated to the JVM instance running, while top will display the total memory for the machine.

Comment: @Mena: There are two java process running on the server and the heap dump is generated out of the process (pid -1890, which is visible in top command output as well) which is consuming more memory on the server.

Comment: Seems the heap dump was not created correctly. There is a separate issue. Will create another question for it.